# Virtual Box Failed to create VirtualBox COM object

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am running Windows 7 64 bit (on a laptop). I just downloaded the latest virtual box binary and it installs but does not start. I get a **Caller RC: CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE** whenever i start VirtualBox.exe. Also there is no process VBoxSVC.exe that is started when i start virtualbox (maybe related to the problem?).

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Take a look at the log file at `%HOMEPATH%\.VirtualBox\VBoxSVC.log`.  See if there is anything interesting in there.

Comment: I don't have a .VirtualBox folder